# Change "value" of dropdown list with php (for mailing purpose)

Tags: php, arrays, email, html-select

I would like to have a dropdown list in my contact form. I use method=post.

I did following

```
<select>
 <option name="dropdown" value=''>Please Choose Dept.</option>
 <option name="dropdown" value='mail1@example.com'>Technical</option>
 <option name="dropdown" value='mail2@example.com'>PR</option>
 <option name="dropdown" value='mail3@example.com'>Sales</option>
</select>

and then php (whatever the rest part)
$emailTo = $_POST['dropdown'];
```

Well it worked, but I don't want to have my mails so open, you know ;)
So I have found another solution, which goes like this

```
<select>
 <option name="dropdown" value=''>Please Choose Dept.</option>
 <option name="dropdown" value='technical'>Technical</option>
 <option name="dropdown" value='pr'>PR</option>
 <option name="dropdown" value='sales'>Sales</option>
</select>

and then php (whatever the rest part)
//PHP
$emails = array('technical' => 'technical@xxxxxx.xxx', 'pr' => 'pr@xxxxxx.xxx'); // etc. as i understand, it should replace the values to the mails :)
 if(array_key_exists($_POST['dropdown']))
  {
    $emailTo = $emails[$_POST['dropdown']];
    //send email to $emailTo
  }
```

Aaaaand... it doesn't work :( Could someone point me what's wrong?
For curious ones I'm using wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

Comment: The `name` needs to be in the `<select>`, not the individual options.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you see @vigour's answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the second argument of array_key_exists, use array_key_exists($_POST['dropdown'],$emails) :D

Comment: Thank you! It worked :)
btw wasn't me, copy&pasted that, I cannot into php :D